# How to count id's per name in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a list of names:

```
lst = ['Albert', 'Carl', 'Julian', 'Mary']
```

and I have a DF:

```
target     id      name
  A       100     Albert
  A       110     Albert
  B       200     Carl
  D       500     Mary
  E       235     Mary
```

I want to make another dataframe counting how many `id` per name in `lst`:

```
lst_names   Count
Albert       2
Carl         1
Julian       0
Mary         2
```

What's the most efficient way to do this considering the list of names has 12k unique names on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check with `value_counts`

```
pd.Categorical(df['name'],lst).value_counts()
Out[894]: 
Albert    2
Carl      1
Julian    0
Mary      2
dtype: int64
```

Or

```
df['name'].value_counts().reindex(lst,fill_value=0)
Out[896]: 
Albert    2
Carl      1
Julian    0
Mary      2
Name: name, dtype: int64
```

Comment: `.reindex()`! Very nice indeed

Answer (score 2):

You can use `value_counts`, and then create an empty Series with `lst` as the index, and then add them together, filling NaN with 0:

```
(df['name'].value_counts() + pd.Series(index=lst, dtype=int)).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
Albert    2
Carl      1
Julian    0
Mary      2
Name: count, dtype: int64
```